# How to Connect an Ember app to a Rails API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js, ember-cli, development-environment

Currently having some trouble understanding how to connect an Ember app to a Rails API in my local dev environment. I'm pretty unfamiliar with this sort of set up, as opposed to just running a purely Rails application.

So run when I'm running these two separate apps, it looks like:

```
Ember app running on `localhost:4200`
Rails API running on `localhost:3000`
```

And both applications are in the same directory

```
Parent Directory
|
|___ API
|
|___ Ember App
```

When I visit both localhost URLs, both the apps are running. The Rails API seems to be fine, but the Ember app displays the default *"There's something wrong"* page that was made, and below is the error I receive in the console:

[image]

I was hoping someone could explain what might be wrong with my set up, that's causing this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have not posted any files here it how it should be setup

Inside Ember define application adapter that has namespace property:

```
export default ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api'
});
```

Inside rails config/routes.rb you should have something like this:

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
  resource :companies
end
```

This resource should be defined inside app/api/companies_controller.rb

```
module Api
  class CompaniesController < ActionController::Base 
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

    def index
    ...
  end
end
```

Once you do this you can start environment like this:

ember server --proxy http://localhost:3000

Note that this is defined by routes not location inside directories. Proxy is also important if it is served separately.

You can check this add-on that helps merge two:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/ember-cli-rails

Hope it helps.

Comment: Note that in my example I am using ActiveModelAdapter. You can use also JSONAPIAdapter. This one has also namespace property: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html#property_host

Comment: Cool. Looks like I had this all set up; the two things I was missing was `ember server --proxy http://localhost:3000` (didn't know about proxies) and `rails s --binding 0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind that Ember routes are different from the Rails API routes. 
The Ember routes are defined in the routes file whereas rails routes are defined in your app depending if you are using controllers or some gem like Grape. So if you hit your Ember app with some route defined in the Rails app it may not work since that route may not exist for the Ember router unless you map exactly the Rails API routes into the Ember router, which is almost never the case.

I recommend you check what routes you have available in your Ember router.